# Getting a complex struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, interop, marshalling

Days ago I made this question: [Passing a complex Struct (with inner array of struct) from C# to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386234/passing-a-complex-struct-with-inner-array-of-struct-from-c-sharp-to-c)

Fortunately it as been answered and the code seems to work.

Now I need to do the oposite case, I mean, I need to get the struct from the C++ dll to my C# code.

I was researching in this site, trying the use of the IntPtr type, but didnt work. Then as my struct in C# was defined correctly I tried to use an out reference.

As a sumary, gonna repost the structs defined in both languages

```
typedef struct _ImParam
{
  UINT Format;
  UINT Resolution;
  UINT ColorDepth;
} IM_PARAM;

typedef struct _sValues
{
  UINT Xpos;
  UINT Ypos;
  UINT Width;
  UINT Height;
  BOOL Milli; 
} S_VALUES;

typedef struct _sProperties
{
  BOOL Enable;
  S_VALUES Properties;
} S_PROPERTIES;

typedef struct _DevParam
{
  BOOL Enable;
  UINT Font;
  char Symbol;
  IM_PARAM Image1;
  IM_PARAM Image2;
  S_PROPERTIES Properties[10];
  UINT FeedMode;
} DevParam;

// more code, comments, etc. etc.

// The function I want to use
BOOL GetParameters( DWORD ID, DevParam  *dParam );
```

This is how I build the structs in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ImParam
{
   public uint Format;
   public uint Resolution;
   public uint ColorDepth;

   public ImParam(uint n)
   {
       Format = n;
       Resolution = 300;
       ColorDepth = 256;
   }
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sValues
{
   public uint Xpos;
   public uint Ypos;
   public uint Width;
   public uint Height;
   public bool Milli;

   public sValues(uint n)
   {
       Xpos = n;
       Ypos = n;
       Width = n;
       Height = n;
       Milli = false;
   }
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sProperties
{
   public bool Enable;
   public sValues Properties;

   public sProperties(int n)
   {
       Enable = false;
       Properties = new sValues(n);
   }
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DevParam
{
   public bool Enable;
   public uint Font;
   public char Symbol;
   public ImParam Image1;
   public ImParam Image2;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
   public sProperties[] Properties;
   public uint FeedMode;

   public DeviceParameters(int n)
   {
       Enable = true;
       Font = 0;
       Symbol = '?';
       Image1 = new ImParam(3);
       Image2 = new ImParam(3);
       Properties = new sProperties[10];
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          Properties[i] = new sProperties(n);
       FeedMode = 1;
   }
};

// This is the method imported from the C++ dll
[DllImport(path, EntryPoint = "?GetParameters@@YGHKPAU_DevParam@@@Z")]
public static extern bool GetParameters(int ID, out DevParam dParam);
```

And here's the call

```
// Already got ID from somewhere else
DevParam DP;
bool res = Class1.GetParameters(ID, out DP);
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + res);
```

The code seems to work, since I'm getting a "true" as result. The problem is it's getting wrong values in the structs members, placing the default ones (always 0 the numbers, always false the booleans), even if I use the SetParam(..) method before (and I know that one works because when I change the image format scanner decreases scanning speed).

What am I missing?

Note: I dont have source code of the .dll

---

Edited:

Been trying with these modifications:

```
// At the dll wrapper class
[DllImport(path, EntryPoint = "?GetParameters@@YGHKPAU_DevParam@@@Z")]
public static extern bool GetParameters(int ID, ref IntPtr dParam);

// At main
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DevParam));
IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
bool res = Class1.GetParameters(ID, ref Ptr);
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + res);
var test = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Ptr, typeof(DevParam));
// No idea what I'll do here
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
```

If I try to print "test", it should give an adress, since it's a pointer, but it's null. Neither know how can I extract the data from the struct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Keywords to research: marshalling , serialization , structure padding , C++ ABI.

Comment: I been looking for those. I made the question because what I found doesnt convince me. Dont feel that's what I'm looking for (or tried those solutions but failed)

Comment: AFAIK `BOOL` should be marshaled as `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)`

Comment: Thanks. Added the marshal. Still get the error.
I'm seeing how to do it with the IntPtr (because I believe answer goes there). Added "ref" keyword and I get a true as result. Seems that's how it can also be passed.
Yet, I'm stuck since dont know what else to do (yeah, it's my first time importing DLL and marshaling stuff, my experience is... 5%?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
// At the dll wrapper class
[DllImport(path, EntryPoint = "?GetParameters@@YGHKPAU_DevParam@@@Z")]
public static extern bool GetParameters(int ID, IntPtr dParam);

// At main
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DevParam));
IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
bool res = Class1.GetParameters(ID, Ptr);
DevParam test = (DevParam)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Ptr, typeof(DevParam));

// For testing purpoises, previously changed the default values with another method
Console.WriteLine(test.Enable);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
```

Had to remove the ref keyword.